# Is there a way to read the blob partially?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, blob

I want to read blob partially. For now I can read whole blob with select query e.g.

```
select image from table where condition
```

But the blob is too big, so I want to read blob partially, with begin pos and length, (e.g. `select partial_read( image, 0, 1024 ) from table where condition`)

I just try some new way, but I have no idea. simply I can make blob split. But I can't, because of legacy system, it is forbidden for me.

Can you tell me keyword? Or way?

I am using 
SQL Server: 2008 R2
OS: Server 2012

Comment: I don't believe there's any way to "read part of a blob".  Q: Exactly what error occurs when you try to read?

Comment: i have some performance issue ( insert image to blob ) , i will try to blob merging, it make insert time better, so i want to blob merging and can read, i can make merging, but i can't read,

Comment: You know, there's nothing that says you have to store the binary object *IN THE DATABASE*.  For example, you can use a [Filestream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/compare-options-for-storing-blobs-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: [SUBSTRING (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql) doesn't only work on string data. It works on char, binary, text, ntext and image data types as well.

Comment: in my case , substring is ok, thank you

Comment: You might want to consider upgrading your database. SQL Server 2008 (all versions) is no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

Using SUBSTRING such as AlwaysLearning suggests, is perfect for my task (which is identifying PDF data falsely stored as TIF in blobs). Saves a ton of time.

Comment: Seems like this should be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: True, I just wanted to add a comment.